# What order are config files loaded under linux when there are multiple sources?

Tags: configuration, postgresql, process-priority

I understand the main principle that local configuration files precede global `/etc/` configuration files. What I really need though is some more detail on this because sometimes it's not obvious.

The example I'd like to know an implicit answer for would be for the following PostgreSQL config files:  `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf` and `/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/pg_hba.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL won't read and merge `pg_hba.conf`. So "only the one in /etc". Note that PostgreSQL config in /etc is specific to Ubuntu and Debian, which use `pg_wrapper`; other Linux distros and other operating systems have PostgreSQL's config inside the data directory.

In general, under Linux config file loading is somewhat application and distro specific. There is unfortunately no standard format, no standard search path, or anything much else.